# how many permutation without fixed points from 2n to NxN

Tags: combinatorics

I was given this following question:
In many how ways can we arrange $n$ pairs of animals (male and female) in to $n$ distinct  rooms so that in each room there will be exactly 2 animals from different species (we can pair 2 from the same gender)?

I tried lots of ways, but I got no where...
I'll be glad if some one can give a hint or direction!
tnx!

Comment: Have you tried the inclusion-exclusion principle? It is not difficult to count in how many ways we have $\geq k$ rooms occupied by two animals of the same species.

Comment: Are the rooms distinct or not?

Comment: yes they are distinct,i sorry i forgot to write it.

Answer (score 1):

A general hint for problems like this:  Carefully compute the first few examples, and then consult the [OEIS](http://oeis.org).  I'll get things started:  When $n=1$, there are $0$ arrangements, while for $n=2$, there are $2$ (male aardvark with male zebra, or male aardvark with female zebra).  So the sequence is

$$0,2,\ldots$$